# Jquery-UI autocomplete asp.net search text box

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have a textbox on my front end, which I am trying to implement an auto suggestion based on what a sql query brings back. I am using the jquery libraries and imported them into my solution. When I go ahead and run this, it hits the "no match error" although I type in a letter in the search box. Am I missing something in my code?

aspx code below:

```
<link href="jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />  
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>  
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        SearchText();
    });
    function SearchText() {
        $("#SearchBox").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "CompanyPage.aspx/GetCompanyName",
                    data: "{'cmpName':'" + document.getElementById('SearchBox').value + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data.d);
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("No Match");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
</script>  

<asp:TextBox ID="SearchBox" placeholder="Enter company name to search on" runat="server" Width="322px" Height="16px" style="margin-left: 22px; margin-top: 0px" OnTextChanged="SearchBox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

aspx.cs code:

```
 [WebMethod] 
        public static List<string> GetCompanyName(string cmpName)
        {
            List<string> cmpResult = new List<string>();
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[searchCompanyName]", cn))
            {
                    cmd.Connection = cn;
                    cn.Open();
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", cmpName);
                    SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        cmpResult.Add(dr["CompanyName"].ToString());
                    }
                    cn.Close();
                    return cmpResult;
            }

        }
```

SQL stored proc:

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[searchCompanyName] 
    @CompanyName varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT CompanyName FROM Company
    WHERE CompanyName like @CompanyName + '%'

END
```

[image]

Comment: Did you check to see if there is anything in `data.d`?

Comment: Dont know how to debug to find out if anything is in data.d ?

Comment: Shouldn't this be like: `success: function (result) {
                        response(result.d);
                    },` ?

Comment: Easy: either `alert(data.d)` or put the word `debugger;` as the first line in `success`

Comment: @faizanrabbani no that does not matter. It can be called anything.

Comment: Tried alert(data.d) and this did not alert anything! So it allowed me to continue to write in the textbox

Comment: @CodingYoshi Okay thanks, @RA19, can you debug `GetCompanyName` and see if it executes properly?

Comment: Check attached image - i got this in my console?

Comment: when i tried alert(data.d) in my error: function

Comment: Internal server error means there is some problem with the server-side code, you'll have to debug it and see.

Comment: OK - it breaks straight after this line:

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CompanyName", cmpName);

Comment: cmpName gets my value correctly. Checked in debug mode

Comment: Well the error is saying there is an issue at the server. Debug your c# code. If you do not know how to use the débugger, watch a tutorial on YouTube.

Comment: Also you cannot do `alert(data.d)` in the `error` function. You have to do `alert(result)`

Comment: @CodingYoshi - Thanks, tried that and got this as the result: [object Object]

Comment: Yes because you need to see what kind of object and then see the error message. But dont worry about that right now, you know the issue is at the server so fix that. Make sure `cmpName` is received at the server. If not fix that. Then make sure the server returns data. Take your time and debug it.

Comment: Ok debugged and changed code

Answer (score 0):

ajax:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    SearchText();
});
function SearchText() {
    $(".autosuggest").autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "CompanyPage.aspx/GetCompanyData",
                data: "{'companyname':'" + document.getElementById('SearchBox').value + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data != null) {

                        response(data.d);
                    }
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

ajax.cs

```
[WebMethod]
        public static List<string> GetCompanyData(string companyname)
    {
        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnection"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);


        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("[searchCompanyName]", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@companyname", companyname);
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(dr["companyname"].ToString());
                }
                return result;
        }
```